# how to get comments, posted on reviews on Facebook page using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to get comments posted on a review. I am trying to get comments using reviews id but no data returns from fb graph api.

Here's the graph api query I'm using  to get all reviews:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/613053785834585/?fields=ratings%7Bopen_graph_story%7D&access_token=accesstoken`

My result is:

```
    {
      "ratings": {
        "data": [
          {
            "open_graph_story": {
              "id": "1301773496640266",
              "message": "improve some more quality not as per standards.......",
              "start_time": "2019-04-08T13:24:47+0000",
              "type": "sellers.rates",
              "data": {
                "recommendation_type": "negative",
                "review_text": "improve some more quality not as per standards.......",
                "is_hidden": false,
                "language": "en",
                "seller": {
                  "id": "613053785834585",
                  "title": "Developer Zone",
                  "type": "profile",
                  "url": "https://www.facebook.com/DeveloperZoneKrishan/"
                },
                "has_review_update": false
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "open_graph_story": {
              "id": "1151783264995390",
              "message": "This review for testing, Please ignore it.",
              "start_time": "2019-04-03T13:21:56+0000",
              "type": "sellers.rates",
              "data": {
                "recommendation_type": "positive",
                "review_text": "This review for testing, Please ignore it.",
                "is_hidden": false,
                "language": "en",
                "seller": {
                  "id": "613053785834585",
                  "title": "Developer Zone",
                  "type": "profile",
                  "url": "https://www.facebook.com/DeveloperZoneKrishan/"
                },
                "has_review_update": false
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "id": "613053785834585"
    }
```

and now i want to get comments posted on last review thats id is 1151783264995390, using:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/1151783264995390/comments?access_token=accesstoken`

but this returns empty like this:

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

I expect it will return comments data posted on specific review ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGY9V.jpg)).

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a bug on Facebook's side. There are currently a couple of open issues on the Facebook developer portal about this problem:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2262278433989990

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/334315677220267